# Why $f$ is an automorphism?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be  a group and $f: G\rightarrow G$ is a function such that  for any $x,y\in G$ we have 
$$f(xf(y))=f(x)y.$$
Then prove that  $f$ is an automorphism of $G$.

Comment: Where is the problem from?  What have you tried?

Comment: first you can find $f(f(y))=y$. if $u = f(y)$, then $f(u) = y$, thus $f(xu) = f(x)f(u)$.

Comment: @Yimin first you have to prove $f(1)=1$. Since we don't know $f$ is a homomorphism, we have to prove that first before we can get $f(f(y))=y$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, you are right.

Comment: take $f(1) = t$, then take $x= 1,y =1$, you got $f(t) = t$, then take $x=1,y =t$, then $f(f(t)) = f(t)f(t)= t^2$, thus $t^2 = t$.

Comment: +1 for your nice question. Indeed Jonas gave you a perfect one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By setting $x=1$ we see that $f\circ f$ is the map $y\mapsto f(1)y$, which is bijective.  Therefore $f$ is also bijective.

From $f(f(1))=f(1)$ and injectiveness we have $f(1)=1$.  It follows that $f\circ f$ is the identity map (in other words, $f=f^{-1}$).  It remains to be shown that $f$ is a homomorphism.

For all $a,b\in G$, $f(ab)=f(af(f(b)))=f(a)f(b)$.